# Group items by the items it holds

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, grouping

*Please note: My question contains pseudo code!*

In my army I have foot soldiers. 
Every soldier is unique: name, strength etc...

All soldiers have inventory. It can be empty.
Inventory can contain: weapons, shields, other items.

I want to group my footsoldiers by their exact inventory.

**Very simple example:**

I have a collection of:

- Weapons: {"AK-47", "Grenade", "Knife"}
- Shields: {"Aegis"}
- OtherItems: {"KevlarVest"}

Collection of footsoldiers. (Count = 6)

- "Joe" : {"AK-47", "Kevlar Vest"}
- "Fred" : {"AK-47"}
- "John" : {"AK-47", "Grenade"}
- "Rambo" : {"Knife"}
- "Foo" : {"AK-47"}
- "Bar" : {"KevlarVest"}

These are the resulting groups (count=5) : (already in specific order now)

- {"AK-47"}
- {"AK-47", "Grenade"}
- {"AK-47", "Kevlar Vest"}
- {"Knife"}
- {"KevlarVest"}

I want to sort the groups by: Weapons, then by shields, then by other items in specific order in which they are declared within their collection.

When I open the inventorygroup {"Knife"} I will find a collection with 1 footsoldier named "Rambo".

*Please note: I have made this simplified version, in order not to distract you with the complexity of the data at hand. In my business case I am working with ConditionalActionFlags, that may hold Conditions of a certain type.*

Hereby I supply a TestMethod that still fails now. 
**Can you rewrite the `GetSoldierGroupings` method so that the `TestSoldierGroupings` method succeeds ?**

```
public class FootSoldier
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Inventory { get; set; }
}

public class ArrayComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[]>
{
    public bool Equals(T[] x, T[] y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T[] obj)
    {
        return obj.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, i) => s + i.GetHashCode(), s => s.GetHashCode());
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestSoldierGroupings()
{
    //Arrange
    var weapons = new[] { "AK-47", "Grenade", "Knife" };
    var shields = new[] { "Aegis" };
    var otherItems = new[] { "KevlarVest" };

    var footSoldiers = new FootSoldier[]
    {
        new FootSoldier() { Name="Joe" , Inventory= new string[]{ "AK-47", "Kevlar Vest" } },
        new FootSoldier() { Name="Fred" , Inventory= new string[]{ "AK-47" } },
        new FootSoldier() { Name="John" , Inventory= new string[]{ "AK-47", "Grenade" } },
        new FootSoldier() { Name="Rambo" , Inventory= new string[]{ "Knife" } },
        new FootSoldier() { Name="Foo" , Inventory= new string[]{ "AK-47" } },
        new FootSoldier() { Name="Bar" , Inventory= new string[]{ "Kevlar Vest" } }
    };

    //Act
    var result = GetSoldierGroupings(footSoldiers, weapons, shields, otherItems);
    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Count, 5);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.First().Key, new[] { "AK-47" });
    Assert.AreEqual(result.First().Value.Count(), 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Last().Key, new[] { "Kevlar Vest" });
    Assert.AreEqual(result[new[] { "Knife" }].First().Name, "Rambo");
}

public Dictionary<string[], FootSoldier[]> GetSoldierGroupings(FootSoldier[] footSoldiers, 
    string[] weapons, 
    string[] shields, 
    string[] otherItems)
{
    //var result = new Dictionary<string[], FootSoldier[]>();
    var result = footSoldiers
        .GroupBy(fs => fs.Inventory, new ArrayComparer<string>())
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToArray());

    //TODO: the actual sorting.

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh if a footsoldier has no items in inventory, thats a group of its own, on top of sorting :-)

Comment: you can enumerate the possible combinations of inventory items and have that enum as a property of the soldier

Comment: Sounds like standard LINQ `GroupBy` with custom comparer eventually. Did you try something? What's the issue?

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf: according to your deleted question: `_appleTrees.SelectMany(atree => atree.Basket.Apples.Where(a => a.DNA.Contains(atree.TreeDNA)));`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thank you for helping! I am afraid to aks questions, people are so fast with downvoting.

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf: true, it is always good to show your own effort or at least mention that you don't have any ideas. That prevents downvotes. Mentioning "please don't downvote" achieves the exact opposite

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your soldiers by a key of combined items. It can be done using custom comparers.
As for me, I would make it simpler by using `String.Join` with separator which cannot be met in any weapon, shield etc.

Assuming that a soldiers has a property `Items` which is an array of strings (like `["AK-47", "Kevlar Vest"]`), you can do something like this:

```
var groups = soldiers
    .GroupBy(s => String.Join("~~~", s.Items))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.First().Items, g => g.ToArray());
```

It will result into a Dictionary where key is unique item set, and value is an array of all soldiers having such set.

You may change this code such that it returns `IGrouping`, array of classes \ structs, `Dictionary`, whatever else convenient for you.
I would go for a `Dictionary` or an array of something like `SoldiersItemGroup[]` with items and soldiers as properties.
Make sure to change such join separator that no weapon can theoretically contain it.

Comment: I have used your ToDictionary() method. But I had to add : 'public class ArrayComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[]>'. Can you help me with the sorting, so that the TestMethod succeeds?